# Auto indent second line of text after "carriage return."

Tags: spacing

I'm writing a how-to chapter for citing texts in various bibliographic formats. I need to define an environment where the second (and any subsequent) lines will be indented an arbitrary length. I can't figure out how to do this without manually inserting a space for each line; but that is agonizing work. Can someone help me define an environment that will do this for me?

I'd like something like this:

```
Tate, Larry. "Some fake article that I wrote about." *Journal of Fake 
     Articles*65.4 (1994): 34-56.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\hangindent3cm
 aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
 aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
 aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
```

[image]

Comment: I had never seen that command. What a powerful command!

Comment: @Sigur If you need to mix with latex constructs eg have a nested list within the hang region it's better to set it up as a special list item shape, (so the nested list knows about the restricted line length)  but usually it's just plain text and the primitive (which is just `\parskip` inverted) is rather simpler

Comment: For what it's worth, use something like `\newenvironment{specialindent}[1][1in]{\setlength{\hangindent}{#1}}{\par}` (or a list)...

Comment: @Werner maybe `\par` in the begin part too?